# Firefox operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs

My code works both with ie and chrome, only firefox fails with this error.

I have added an ajax request with url to my container.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'attachment/uploadAttachment',
            scope: this,
            params: {
                projectId: this.projectId,
                draftNumber: this.draftNumber
            },
            success: function(form, action) {

            },
    })
```

I`m using ext js 3.4 framework for my ui side.

I get this on firefox :

```
{"raw":["SecurityError: The operation is insecure."
"http://localhost:8080/MySupplierInvoices/plugins/my-apps-ext-js-common-0.1/js/overrides/Ext.form.Field.js?_debugResources=y&n=1380786192461"
21]
```

Comment: That looks like a cross domain issue. Apparently not pertaining to the code you've posted. Look at the URL in the message... Are you using some kind of class loader?

Comment: I`m trying to upload file.

`setRawValue : function(v){
if (Ext.isString(v)) {
v = Ext.util.Format.decodeGreaterThanAndLessThanSymbols(v);
}
return this.rendered ? (this.el.dom.value = (Ext.isEmpty(v) ? '' : v)) : '';
}, `

the error is pointing to the `return` line